# Why is my counter not working in this Python 3 sort and count implementation?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm extremely new to Python 3 and I'm having some difficulty getting used to it. As a practice exercise, our professor instructed us to implement a sort and count function that counts the number of inversions in an array and returns the count and the sorted array in O(nlogn) time.

Something like `print sort_and_count([1,3, 5, 2, 4])` is expected to return `([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)`.

I got a lot of help from a friend on the merge function, so I'm banking on the issue being there, but it's a little hard for me to understand and my friend isn't available to help clarify. The code goes as follows:

```
def merge(arr,l,m,r):
    global count;
    n1=m-l+1;
    n2=r-m;

    L=[0] * n1;
    R=[0] * n2;

    for i in range(0,n1):
        L[i]=arr[l+i];

    for i in range (0,n2):
        R[i]=arr[m+1+i];

    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=l;

    while i<n1 and j  <n2:
        if L[i]<=R[j]:
            arr[k]=L[i];
            i+=1;

        else:
            arr[k]=R[j];
            count=count+n1-i;
            j+=1;
        k+=1;

    while(j<n2):
        arr[k]=R[j];
        j+=1;
        k+=1;

    while(i<n1):
        arr[k]=L[i];
        i+=1;
        k+=1;

def merge_sort(arr,l,r):
    if(l<r):
        m=(l+r)//2;
        merge_sort(arr,l,m);
        merge_sort(arr,m+1,r);
        merge(arr,l,m,r);
    return;

def Inversions(arr):

    global count;
    merge_sort(arr,0,len(arr)-1);
    return count;

def sort_and_count(arr):
    tcounter = (abs(Inversions(arr)))

    result = "(%s, %i)" %(arr, tcounter)
    count = 0;
    return result;

count = 0;
```

As you can see, the sort_and_count function takes an array as parameter, which is then put through the merge_sort and merge functions in order to sort and obtain the amount of inversions. The fuzzy bit for me is the merge function, as that is the part I got help with and I don't quite know how to troubleshoot it.

The very specific way of printing the result at the end of the sort_and_count function is due to using a webpage which reads that whole thing as a string. I cannot change the parameter passed onto sort_and_count, and the way the string is formatted cannot be changed either.

Initially, `print (sort_and_count([1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]))` is tested, which outputs `([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)`. This is correct and the code passes the test.

The next test is the problematic one, as `print(sort_and_count([70,35,21,12,56,38,98,42]))` is now tested, which returns `([12, 21, 35, 38, 42, 56, 70, 98], 19)`. The expected output is `([12, 21, 35, 38, 42, 56, 70, 98], 12).`

There is an issue regarding the counter, as it returns 19 instead of the expected 12, but once again I do not comprehend the merge code. If anyone could explain the merge code, that would be swell. Of course, I'm looking for a fix to properly handle the counter most of all. Initially I thought somehow the counter wasn't getting reset, so I tried moving the counter = 0 declaration around, but that of course didn't solve anything. If anyone could help, that would be great. Thank you so much for being patient with me!

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks as though your code comes from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/.

Perhaps the comments in the python 3 source and the explanation there will help you.